# Windows Task Scheduler Unstopped

Tags: windows-server-2012, taskscheduler

in windows server 2012, i have created a task scheduler. The task schdeuler starts the job in given start date and time. But it is not stopping or ending at the given time.

Please give me any idea about this. How to end the job automatically as it keeps on running even after the end time is completed.

Comment: why tagged with C#?

Comment: is there a proper way?